# The difference in testing iPhone and Simulator iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, ios-simulator

I have some problem

I am writing an application that is tested in the simulator. all ok

Test decided on iPhone. And where I go check on the phone but it is in fact not be

```
- (BOOL) myChecker
{
/// ....

if .....
{
return YES
} else {
return NO
}

......
- (void) something {

BOOL myVar = [self myChecker];
if (myVar) {
// .....
} else {
//.....
}
}
```

everything is OK in the simulator myVar = NO;
and iPhones get myVar = YES;

how to understand?

**UPDATE (solved)**

```
   - (BOOL) myChecker
    {
      BOOL CheckSomething;

    /// ....
      if ....something {
         CheckerSomething = YES
        } else {
 if .....
{
}
}

    if (CheckerSomething)
    {
    return YES
    } else {
    return NO
    }
```

in xcode simulator CheckerSomething is begin = NO;
but in iPhone **CheckerSomething = YES** when loading variable in memory

that is error

Forcibly put to NO is decide problem

sorry for my english

Comment: if I can use iPhone with debugger in Xcode I can search errors, but in   simulator all ok, and can't understand where error

Comment: sorry i don't know, what debugger use in tested iphone! Now I will try to identify what the problem is

Comment: By convention in Objective-C variables begin with a lower case letter and class names begin with an upper case letter. The exception is a variable that begins with a well understood acronym such as HTML. Changing `CheckerSomething` to `checkerSomething` will make your code more readable and allow the Analyzer to better check the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best guess is that there is some variable that is not initialized and getting an initial value that is different. ARC helps with this because it initializes method variables (automatics) to nil (0) by default.

Run Analyze on your code and fix any warnings.

Trace through the code in the Xcode debugger (it is available both in the simulator on the iPhone device) to see what is happening statement by statement. Set some breakpoints such as at the top of the `myChecker` and `something` methods.